# cbind command is not implemented in the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, cbind

My code and data are similar to the following example(in R), but in the code below, the cbind command is not implemented in the for loop, and eventually t1 is not added to A, since the number of columns is not equal to each other. Please help me.

```
test <- data.frame(c(2, 3), 
                   c("b", "a"), 
                   c("f", "t"), 
                   c("T", "F"))
names(test) <- c("x", "y", "d", "L")

A <- data.frame(c(1, 2, 3), 
                c("a", "b", "c"), 
                c("f", "f", "t"),
                c("T", "T", "F"),
                 c(2, 2, 3))
names(A) <- c("x", "y", "d", "L", "n")

for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  t1 <- test[i, ]
  if (t1$d == "f") {
    A_reduct <- A[, c(1:2)]
    test_reduct <- test[, c(1:2)]
    mix_test_A <- rbind(A_reduct, test_reduct)
    dist_mix_test_A <- as.matrix(FD::gowdis(mix_test_A))
    idxs_mix_test_A <- KernelKnn::distMat.knn.index.dist(
        dist_mix_test_A, 
        TEST_indices = c(4:5), 
        k = 1, 
        threads = 1, 
        minimize = T
    )
    nn_test_A <- idxs_mix_test_A$test_knn_idx
    x <- nn_test_A[i]
    lbltest <- test[i, 4]
    lblgroup <- A[x, 4]
    if (lbltest == lblgroup) {
      y <- A[x, 5]
      t1 <- cbind(t1, n = y)
      A <- rbind(A, t1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in `t1<-cbind(t1,group=y)` change it to `t1<-cbind(t1,n=y)` and it should work

Comment: Yes, it is completely correct and here it works with this change, but in my main code, which is similar to this code, cbind is not executed. Please help me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which `cbind`? the second last?  What is the error message?

Comment: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match